# How to use F string in R to save as xlsl along side date

Tags: r

How do I use the F string in r

I have a data frame that I want to save as xlsl but the data frame is something that wound continuously be dropping day by day

for example

yesterday report would be analyzed today

so I want to automate the report in such a way that the data frame name would also carry yesterday date

see below

`yesterday <- Sys.date () -1` (this gives yesterday date)

now, I want to include the yesterday variable to generate the report as excel

I have tried

F string in r using gsub library
`write_xlsx(ecosftp, "Mydata_vtu_autoreport_{yesterday}.xlsx")` .. but its not working

I want the result to look like this so that anytime he save the report, it will always save as system date minus 1 which gives yesterday date

```
write_xlsx(ecosftp, "Mydata_vtu_autoreport_2021-10-09.xlsx")
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the `glue` package. Try `write_xlsx(ecosftp, glue::glue("Mydata_vtu_autoreport_{yesterday}.xlsx"))`

Comment: @Phil thanks it works fine